# iosARM32 vs iosARM64 vs iosX64 while creating Kotlin Multiplatform Library

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I want to create a Kotlin Multiplatform Library which will support ios. While creating the project, when I try to add a new target as iOS, it provides me with three options,

- iosARM32
- iosARM64
- iosX64

what are these options and which one to choose for iOS/iPhones or iPads?

library MPP module

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer iosARM32 is for older iOS devices(iPhone 5 and low), iOS ARM64 is for the latest iOS devices(after iPhone 5s), and iOSX64 is for iOS simulators. So, imo iOSARM64 will work for most of the devices